# Consulta me resta 2 en lugar de 1

Tags: php, mysql

Buen dia estoy tratando de ejecutar una consulta donde cada vez que la ejecuto me reste 1 a un campo entero de una tabla en MySQL al ejecutar la pura consulta desde phpmyadmin me resta correctamente 1 pero al ejecutar la url desde localhost me resta la cantidad de 2 alguien sabe porque sera?
Esta es mi consulta:

```
    <?php

    require "conn.php";

    $id_fechas = $_GET["id_fechas"];

    $sql="UPDATE fechas SET cupos_disponibles = cupos_disponibles -'1' WHERE id_fechas = '$id_fechas'";
    mysqli_query ($mysqli, $sql);

    if ($mysqli->query($sql)) {
        echo "Actualiza";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $mysqli->error;
    }

    mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

Comment: cuantos registros hay???

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent tengo 10 registros de ejemplo

Comment: con la misma fecha???

Comment: Si @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent por eso le he puesto un where a la consulta id_fechas para que me reste el campo cupos_disponibles donde id_fechas sea igual a 8 por ejemplo

Comment: si hay 2 registros id_fechas =8 lo restara 2 veces ...

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent mm no comprendo muy bien como así que estará 2 veces si el id solo esta 1 vez ?

Comment: si esta solo una ves retara solo una vez..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás ejecutando la consulta dos veces:

```
$sql="UPDATE fechas SET cupos_disponibles = cupos_disponibles -'1' WHERE id_fechas = '$id_fechas'";
// Primera ejecución
mysqli_query ($mysqli, $sql);

// Segunda ejecución, te recomiendo eliminar la anterior
if ($mysqli->query($sql)) {
    echo "Actualiza";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Otra opción, sería usar una variable para guardar el resultado de la consulta:

```
$sql="UPDATE fechas SET cupos_disponibles = cupos_disponibles -'1' WHERE id_fechas = '$id_fechas'";
// Ejecutar consulta y guardar resultado en variable
$resultado = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $sql);
// Analizar variable
if ($resultado) {
    echo "Actualiza";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, esto era el problema, te lo agradezco!